# Get JavaScript result in Powershell

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I have a CSHTML file which has a block `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` inside.

It will show usernames:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result2.Users.length; i++) {
    var item = "<li style='width:100%;'>" + result2.Users[i].TchatEngineId.toString() + " | " + result2.Users[i].Pseudo + "</li>";
```

Now I want to get this result in Powershell, anyone knows how to do it?

I tried with `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Invoke-WebRequest`, but it always returns the source code HTML and not the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to automate with the internet explorer COM object.

```
function wait4IE($ie=$global:ie){
    while ($ie.busy -or $ie.readystate -lt 4){start-sleep -milliseconds 200}
}


$global:ie=new-object -com "internetexplorer.application"
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("http://domain.com/file.html")
wait4IE

$names=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("li")
$names|%{$_.innerText}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it actually works. But I need to put this script to my server for monitoring and it'll run every second, I don't want to use ie because it takes too much resource.

Comment: don't make ie visible and don't forget to quit ie `$ie.quit()` at the end of the script, this shall not consume so much ressource.... every seconds seems a bit too much (time taken to start ie, open url and parse page....)

Comment: I'm figuring how to do this directly by JavaScript, if there exists some way to get my JS variables in Shell.

Comment: Does this mean if I want to automate the web application, which depends on JavaScript extensively, using PowerShell, then the only option (other than IE COM Object) is to use PowerShell+Selineum+Chrome WebDrive? I tried using `Invoke-WebRequest` but the response has JavaScript which is needed to continue loading the website. Any feedback on this please?